# VBA Code Logic VS SQL Code

Tags: sql-server, vba

Here it is I need access function translated to SQL below are both I don't get same results what am I missing? There is minor variance when I run it against the tables. Access Code is the correct one I just need to make sure my SQL code does same thing as access.

Thanks!

--ACCESS VBA CODE:

```
Public Function DelDuplicates()

'save the deleted double counts
DoCmd.OpenQuery "QrySavetrash"


     Dim Mysqlfin, MysqlTrd As String
     Dim Myrecordfin As ADODB.Recordset
     Dim MyrecordTrd As ADODB.Recordset

     Mysqlfin = "select * from TBL_TEMP1"
     MysqlTrd = "select * from TBL_TEMP2"

     Set Myrecordfin = New ADODB.Recordset
     Myrecordfin.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
     Myrecordfin.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
     Myrecordfin.LockType = adLockOptimistic
     Myrecordfin.Open Mysqlfin

     Set MyrecordTrd = New ADODB.Recordset
     MyrecordTrd.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
     MyrecordTrd.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
     MyrecordTrd.LockType = adLockOptimistic
     MyrecordTrd.Open MysqlTrd


     If Not MyrecordTrd.EOF Then
         MyrecordTrd.MoveFirst
    End If
    If Not Myrecordfin.EOF Then
    Myrecordfin.MoveFirst
    End If

   If MyrecordTrd.EOF Then
       MsgBox " Table TBL_TEMP2 is empty, please check"
   End If

   If Myrecordfin.EOF Then
       MsgBox "Table TBL_TEMP1 is empty, please check to make the preprocessing meaningful"
   End If


       RowNo = 0
    Do While Not MyrecordTrd.EOF

          Do While Not Myrecordfin.EOF

            If MyrecordTrd!Invoice = Myrecordfin!INV_NO Then

               If IsNull(MyrecordTrd!Ck_No) Then MyrecordTrd!Ck_No = " "
               If IsNull(Myrecordfin!Ck_No) Then Myrecordfin!Ck_No = " "

               If (MyrecordTrd!Ck_No = Myrecordfin!Ck_No) Or (Nz(MyrecordTrd!Ck_No) = Nz(Myrecordfin!Ck_No)) Then
                  MyrecordTrd.Delete
                  RowNo = RowNo + 1
                  Exit Do
               End If
            End If
            If Not Myrecordfin.EOF Then
                 Myrecordfin.MoveNext
            End If

          Loop


        Myrecordfin.MoveFirst

     If Not MyrecordTrd.EOF Then
        MyrecordTrd.MoveNext
     End If
    Loop

MyrecordTrd.Close
Myrecordfin.Close
'dbinfo.Close

Set MyrecordTrd = Nothing
Set Myrecordfin = Nothing
MsgBox " preprocessing is done " & RowNo & " duplicate records have been deleted"
'Set dbinfo = Nothing

End FunctionPublic Function DelDuplicates()

'save the deleted double counts
DoCmd.OpenQuery "QrySavetrash"
```

---SQL 2012 CODE

```
 UPDATE [dbo].[TBL_TEMP1] SET [CK_NO] = LTRIM(RTRIM([CK_NO]))

 UPDATE [dbo].[TBL_TEMP2] SET [CK_NO] = LTRIM(RTRIM([CK_NO]))

 UPDATE [dbo].[TBL_TEMP1] SET [INV_NO] = LTRIM(RTRIM([INV_NO]))     

 UPDATE [dbo].[TBL_TEMP2] SET [Invoice] = LTRIM(RTRIM([Invoice])

 UPDATE [dbo].[TBL_TEMP1] SET [CK_NO] = ' ' WHERE ISNULL([CK_NO], '0') = '0'

 UPDATE [dbo].[TBL_TEMP2] SET [CK_NO] = ' ' WHERE ISNULL([CK_NO], '0') = '0'

 UPDATE [dbo].[TBL_TEMP1] SET [INV_NO] = ' ' WHERE ISNULL([INV_NO], '0') = '0'

 UPDATE [dbo].[TBL_TEMP2] SET [Invoice] = ' ' WHERE ISNULL( [Invoice], '0') = '0'

 DELETE FROM [dbo].[TBL_TEMP2] FROM  [dbo].[TBL_TEMP2] 
 LEFT JOIN [dbo].[TBL_TEMP1] ON [dbo].[TBL_TEMP2].[Invoice] =  [TBL_TEMP1].[INV_NO]             
 WHERE [dbo].[TBL_TEMP2].[Ck_No] =  [TBL_TEMP1].[CK_NO]

 DELETE FROM [dbo].[TBL_TEMP2] FROM  [dbo].[TBL_TEMP1] 
 LEFT JOIN [dbo].[TBL_TEMP2] ON  [TBL_TEMP1].[INV_NO] = [dbo].[TBL_TEMP2].[Invoice] 
 WHERE [TBL_TEMP1].[CK_NO] = [dbo].[TBL_TEMP2].[Ck_No]
```

Comment: Instead of letting your VBA function explain what are you trying to do, why not you write a few words yourself? at the moment only the people who know VBA and SQL Server both can answer your question.

Comment: Seems like you never call `Update` on your recordsets?

Comment: Second that. I *do* know both VBA and SQL Server, and I still don't know what you're trying to do because I don't have time to look through all that code and figure it out. A short explanation, in your own words, would make all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL should look something like this to do the same thing VBA is doing. It appears that you are trying to remove records of tbl_temp2 with matching invoice and check# (or empty check#) from tbl_temp1.

```
delete a
from tbl_temp2 a 
inner join tbl_temp1 b
  on a.invoice = b.inv_no
  and case when a.ck_no is null then -1 else a.ck_no end 
  = case when b.ck_no is null then -1 else b.ck_no end ;
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20417/1

I took your VBA code and created the same data in MS Access 2013, and ran the VBA code against it. The results were identical to the results from SQL.

The statement matches records from both tables based on invoice number and check number. If it finds a match, that record is removed from `tbl_temp2`. For null check numbers, a -1 is used on the fly.

VBA matches invoice number and check number also. In addition, if check number is null it is converted to an empty string (just like I've used -1) and matched.